# Separate regressions approach vs. interaction term approach

Tags: hypothesis-testing, interaction, regression-coefficients

I am writing my thesis in finance, and my thesis advisor want me to do a categorical analysis, where I include *control variables*. He tells me I cannot simply include interaction terms (i.e. category x interest variable) in my model, unless I can ascertain the reader that the categories do not differ on any of the control variables. (Otherwise, these variables need to be interacted with the category as well). As an alternative, he advises me to run separate regressions and compare the coefficients in some kind of test. This should correct the above issue, since any possible interaction between the category and the control variable will then be captured. My question is: How to do this? I know of a z-test

[image]

which, among other statistical teaching books, is described in Cohen & Cohen (1983) and Keith (2014). But does anyone know how reliable this test is, and what are its assumptions? No one on the Internet seems to know much about this test, and articles/books writing about the test do not discuss it in much detail, so I simply wonder if anyone can recommend this test. Furthermore, can anyone tell me of the drawbacks - as well as the advantages - of both approaches (running separate regressions versus including interaction terms) apart from those described above? To your info, the separate regressions include the same dependent variable as well as control variables. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Interaction is a product term of two predictor variables in your regression model. If you use separated models(separated by one of your interested variable),  there will no such product terms in your model, then how can you catch any interactions with the variable?  If there were no interactions, two separated models should  be the same a combined model, but by using separated models you lost information for the variable you used to separate the model. Therefore, two separated models have no any advantages compare to a combined model and possibly with interaction terms.

Comment: If you fit seperate models by segmenting on some variable, you are interacting that segment variable with all other variables in your model(s). This is a mathematical equivelence